# where is ADB, Android Debug Bridge, components source code located on Android open source project

Tags: android, adb, android-source

From [this article](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html), I know the Android Debug Bridge is composed of three components:

1. ADB Client
2. ADB Server
3. Daemon on equipment or emulator

I would like to get deeper understanding of those components from their respective source code. For now, I found:

1. ADB Client: ./system/core/adb/adb_client
2. ADB Server: ./system/core/adb/adb
3. Daemon on equipment or emulator: don't really know where it is located on framework project...

Comment: why won't you read https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/adb/Android.mk

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The source code for all 3 parts of `ADB` is in the same [system/adb](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/adb/+/master/) folder.

Comment: Good overview here : https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/adb/OVERVIEW.TXT

Comment: Now it gives 404. Is there an up-to-date link?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who mind still be interested in this question after so many years, here is the latest source code repository's url:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/modules/adb/