# How can I communicate between a Windows App and an Android App using the USB cable?

Tags: android, .net, windows, usb

I would like to communicate from a .Net UWP app to an Android device to send and receive data.

For this, I have to activate the "USB Debugging" feature of the Android Device and I have to install an App on it.

If I'm right, I have to use the "[Accessory](https://source.android.com/docs/core/interaction/accessories/aoa#attempt-to-start-in-accessory-mode)" of the USB Manager in the Android App anyway.

For this, I have to implement a related daemon in my UWP App to open the Accessory of the Android device.

Unfortunately, I can't find further information how to realize this.

The solution should work on any Windows installation and any Android device without installing further software / hardware.

**How can I communicate between a Windows App and an Android App using the USB cable?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reference to [Android Open Accessory (AOA) feature](https://source.android.com/docs/core/interaction/accessories/protocol) has the Android device is acting as USB accessory and the counter-party device is configured as USB Host.

An important point is that with AOA on Android the device needs an [Android app to communicate](https://source.android.com/docs/core/interaction/accessories/custom#connecting-over-usb) with the other side:

> If you use the general accessory protocol to communicate with your accessory (rather than the adb or audio protocol), you must provide an Android app that can detect the connection of your USB accessory and establish communication.

If you do not want to write an Android app, you are limited to either the [Android Debug Bridge (adb) protocol](https://github.com/cstyan/adbDocumentation), source directions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21326303/295004) or via Windows Media Transfer Protocol (MTP) which with a search brings up libraries like [libmtp](https://github.com/libmtp/libmtp).

Comment: Thank you, it works for me. But to switch to the AOA mode, I have to enable the USB debugging first to connect from my Windows App to the Android device. Additional, while AOA is active, I can't use MTP and RNDIS furthermore. Do you have a solution, without this issues too?

Comment: From what I understand you should be able to run AOA without USB debugging using different Protocol IDs: https://source.android.com/docs/core/interaction/accessories/aoa2 Trying to have different protocols run at the same time doesn't make sense to me as any endpoint driver wants exclusive use.

Comment: Until now, I didn't find a way to activate the AOA without using the USB ADB interface. To use it, I need to activate the USB debugging.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use mtpmount.

1. Install Dokany on PC.
2. Use mtpmount command tool to mount the Android device as a drive

Then you can traverse the directories and open/close files like on a Windows drives.

Of course, connect the Android device on USB, wake it up, and make sure its USB is on MTP transfer mode.